# Using Room without ViewModel

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

I just started using android room. Only problem is,
It takes several layers for db interaction.
Table Class -> Dao Interface -> Database Repo -> ViewModels

And in each layer, code repetition is there.

As if I directly call queries from Repo, without viewModels, it will not allow. Because call without viewModel observer becomes synchronous, which blocks main thread.

Either there must be standard way to call repo asynchronously, or some hacks. 
May be we can use some Async generic class, which lets you pass queries and return result to main thread.

Possible hack. Don't knwo if it is correct way.

```
    AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            List<User> users = apiService.getAllUsers();
            if(users.size()>0)
            {
                System.out.println("Total users:"+users.size());
                System.out.println("Email:"+users.get(0).getEmail());
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: *Because call without ViewModel observer becomes synchronous, which blocks main thread.* **You don't need ViewModel** to make your call asynchronous because it only requires LiveData. I think your question should be *Is it possible to use Room without Android Architecture library?*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use an [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask) for this without the need for ViewModels.

```
AsyncTask.execute {
            val entity = daoInterface.queryFunction()
            ...
        }
```

Comment: AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                List<User> users = apiService.getAllUsers();
               
            }
        });

Comment: If this is what you meant.

Answer (score 5):

If you are just testing Room then just call

```
.allowMainThreadQueries()
```

If you are building a real app there is no point in skipping this Android Architecture.

Comment: I agree I should follow the architecture. But, it makes four layers. I have 20+ tables to be maintained.

Answer (score 4):

The layers that you see explained [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/guide) or in your app do not introduce code repetition, it may seem like so, but it makes your app modular. If your application scales and you need to reuse or change something it will be much easier.

And additionally, `ViewModel` does not make the calls asynchronous. What makes them work is `LiveData` (when you wrap you return type in `LiveData` in Dao class).
`ViewModel` serves to abstract away the non-view related logic from the View (Activity or Fragment), and lets the data survive configuration change, additionally with `ViewModel` you will avoid having a God `Activity` that handles everything.

You have several options:

1) You can use `AsyncTask` mentioned by @EarlOfEgo in order to perform `insert`. And when you `query` your database, just wrap the return type in `LiveData` and that's it. A small example of an AsyncTask, taken from the [codelab page 8](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view/#7):

```
private static class insertAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Word, Void, Void> {

    private WordDao mAsyncTaskDao; 

    insertAsyncTask(WordDao dao) {
        mAsyncTaskDao = dao;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(final Word... params) {
        mAsyncTaskDao.insert(params[0]);
        return null;
    }
}
```

2) If you don't need to observe the changes in your database then you can avoid `LiveData` altogether and handle the execution of all the queries and inserts manually on a separate thread. Or another option is to receive only one update from the `LiveData` and unregister the listener (or I believe there is an implementation of a `LiveData` that receives only a single update).

3) Or you can just `.allowMainThreadQueries()`

Comment: Thank you @LieForBananas for such detailed answer. I'll go with AsyncTask as suggested by EarlOfEgo. I don't find any usage of standard architecture as of now. I'll see later if things go wrong.